# C# casting issue

Tags: c#, linq, casting

Why if i write

```
char ch = 0;
```

I get compiler error as I would axpect, instead

```
bool allZero = "000".All(ch => ch == 0);
```

I don't get any error.
C# is strongly typed and I'd prefer to be warning in this case.

That was a bug in my software.

Comment: What exactly should that warning be telling you? What's wrong with the comparison `ch == 0`?

Comment: There is an implicit cast from `char` to `int`, so that's the reason why that compiles. It's not the compiler's fault but your own if you don't use `ch == '0' `

Comment: The comparison seems to use incompatible types, as `ch` is of type `char` and `0' is of type `int`.

Comment: The conversion from `char` to `int` is implicit, while the conversion from `int` to `char` is explicit. That's all.

Comment: btw: semantically it seems you meant `ch == '0'` anyway (`'0' != 0`)

Comment: That btw, would have been a very easy verification for a unit test

Comment: It is worth noting that `int foo = '0';` will compile fine which is possibly the missing piece of logic for when you were trying to work out why this happened. Essentially a char can become and int but an int can't become a char (implicitly).

Comment: Warning: an empty string will also give `true` for `"".All(c => c == '0')`, because no character violates the predicate.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes i know that's my fault, but I just exepected to be warned. I didn't know about implicit numeric conversions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in the C# language specification.

***6.1.2 Implicit numeric conversions*** states:

> The implicit numeric conversions are:
>
> (... some text omitted)
>
> •  From char to ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal.

And goes on to explicitly state:

> There are no implicit conversions to the char type, so values of the other integral types do not automatically convert to the char type

***7.3.6.2 Binary numeric promotions*** states:

> Binary numeric promotion occurs for the operands of the predefined +, –, *, /, %, &, |, ^, **==**, !=, >, <, >=, and <= binary operators. Binary numeric promotion implicitly converts both operands to a common type which, in case of the non-relational operators, also becomes the result type of the operation. Binary numeric promotion consists of applying the following rules, in the order they appear here:
>
> • If either operand is of type decimal, the other operand is converted to type decimal, or a binding-time error occurs if the other operand is of type float or double.
>
> (... some text omitted)
>
> •  Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

So when `char == 0` is compiled, the compiler will promote the char to an int before generating the comparison code.

There is nothing in the standard that allows for an `int` to be implicitly converted to a `char` (even if it is a constant value in the valid range for a `char`), and in fact it is explicitly disallowed - which is why `char ch = 0;` is *not* allowed.